# MySQL error "An alias was previously found" when an alias isn't in the query

Tags: mysql, import, phpmyadmin

I have a very odd error while trying to perform an update on a database. This is on an Ubuntu 16.04 server using MySQL 5.7.19-0ubuntu0.16.04.1. The query is:

UPDATE `athlet_teamseason` SET `offkeyreturners` = 'test' WHERE `athlet_teamseason`.`id` = 29701;

The MySQL error is:

## 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '`offkeyreturners` = 'test' WHERE `athlet_teamseason`.`id` = 29701' at line 1

I am doing this in phpMyAdmin, and it gives a bit more information:

2 errors were found during analysis.

An alias was previously found. (near " " at position 50)
An alias was previously found. (near "'test'" at position 51)

If I try this update directly in the phpMyAdmin user interface (search for record, edit field value, submit form) it works, and the query shown is:

UPDATE `athlet_teamseason` SET `offkeyreturners` = 'test' WHERE `athlet_teamseason`.`id` = 29701;

which appears to be identical.  HOWEVER, if I do a string comparison between the two I get:

[image: Diff showing query differences]

So while they appear to be the same, there is a difference somewhere.

The queries were created from a table in a database, using concatenation and referencing cells in a source table.  For example:

="UPDATE `athlet_teamseason` SET `offkeyreturners` = '"&data!I2&"' WHERE `athlet_teamseason`.`id` = "&data!A2&";"

I have thousands of these and they all produce the same error.  I've done this dozens of times in older servers, might be an issue with MySQL 5.7?

Comment: I'm guessing you have some non-printing characters in your fields.

Comment: Thanks, that occurred to me too.  I used my cursor keys to move over the text to see if I could detect any, but no luck.

Comment: Cursor keys won't necessarily help with non-whitespace characters; you can usually get better results looking for discrepancies with the LENGTH function on values you know you're having issues with; or you might have some luck with regular expressions.

Comment: Thanks, I retyped my template query by hand, and now it works.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Uueerdo, I eliminated non-printing characters in my query.

Comment: You might want to show how you filtered them out in your situation so it can be of use to others.

Comment: I  gave up trying to find them.  I just retyped the query by hand without copy/pasting from my example query.